# Central alignment within div with inline display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just a quick question here if i may, I'm very new so go steady on my :)

I'm trying to centralise an inline social sharing div on my site but seem to be struggling. The div is within other div's that are centred but this seems to always float to the left.

Here's the html

```css
#share-buttons img {
  width: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="share-buttons">



  <a href="mailto:?Subject=Simple Share 
          Buttons&amp;Body=I%20saw%20this%20and%20thought%20of%20you!%20 
          https://auto-glanz.co.uk/how-to-use-a-clay-bar">
    <img src="email.png" alt="Email" />
  </a>


  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://auto-
          glanz.co.uk/how-to-use-a-clay-bar" target="_blank">
    <img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
  </a>


  <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://auto-glanz.co.uk/how-
          to-use-a-clay-bar" target="_blank">
    <img src="google.png" alt="Google" />
  </a>


  <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?
          mini=true&amp;url=https://auto-glanz.co.uk/how-to-use-a-clay-bar" target="_blank">
    <img src="linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" />
  </a>


  <a href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement
        ('script');e.
        setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute
        ('charset','UTF-
        8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?
        r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());">
    <img src="pinterest.png" alt="Pinterest" />
  </a>


  <a href="http://reddit.com/submit?url=https://auto-glanz.co.uk/how-to-
          use-a-clay-bar&amp;title=How to use a clay bar" target="_blank">
    <img src="reddit.png" alt="Reddit" />
  </a>


  <a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=https://auto-
          glanz.co.uk/how-to-use-a-clay-bar&amp;title=How to use a clay bar" target="_blank">
    <img src="stumbleupon.png" alt="StumbleUpon" />
  </a>


  <a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=https://auto-
          glanz.co.uk/how-to-use-a-clay-bar&amp;title=How to use a clay bar" target="_blank">
    <img src="tumblr.png" alt="Tumblr" />
  </a>


  <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https://auto-glanz.co.uk/how-to-
          use-a-clay-bar&amp;text=Clay%20Bar%20Guide&amp;hashtags=claybarguide" target="_blank">
    <img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" />
  </a>


  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.print()">
    <img src="print.png" alt="Print" />
  </a>


</div>
```

I can get them to centre relatively easy but they stack on top of each other, although its no doubt an easy task I'm struggling a little.

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: You want to center the `div`? So where is the css for it?

Comment: If you want to center the div , add this line to your css code : #share-buttons {text-align:center;}

Answer (score 0):

```
#share-buttons{text-align:center;}
```

just add this

Comment: Brilliant all sorted thanks.

totally didn't realise i was missing the style for the entire div and only had the style for the div img 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display:flex` property to the wrapper element.

```
#share-buttons {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
}
```

```css
#share-buttons img {
  width: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

#share-buttons {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
}
```

```html
<div id="share-buttons">
  <a href="mailto:?Subject=Simple Share 
  Buttons&amp;Body=I%20saw%20this%20and%20thought%20of%20you!%20 
      https://auto-glanz.co.uk/how-to-use-a-clay-bar">
    <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/email.png" alt="Email" />
  </a>


  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://auto-glanz.co.uk/how-to-use-a-clay-bar" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
  </a>


  <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://auto-glanz.co.uk/how-
      to-use-a-clay-bar" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/google.png" alt="Google" />
  </a>


  <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?
      mini=true&amp;url=https://auto-glanz.co.uk/how-to-use-a-clay-bar" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" />
  </a>


  <a href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement
    ('script');e.
    setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute
    ('charset','UTF-
    8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?
    r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());">
    <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/pinterest.png" alt="Pinterest" />
  </a>


  <a href="http://reddit.com/submit?url=https://auto-glanz.co.uk/how-to-
      use-a-clay-bar&amp;title=How to use a clay bar" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/reddit.png" alt="Reddit" />
  </a>


  <a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=https://auto-
      glanz.co.uk/how-to-use-a-clay-bar&amp;title=How to use a clay bar" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/stumbleupon.png" alt="StumbleUpon" />
  </a>


  <a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=https://auto-
      glanz.co.uk/how-to-use-a-clay-bar&amp;title=How to use a clay bar" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/tumblr.png" alt="Tumblr" />
  </a>


  <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https://auto-glanz.co.uk/how-to-
      use-a-clay-bar&amp;text=Clay%20Bar%20Guide&amp;hashtags=claybarguide" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" />
  </a>


  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.print()">
    <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/print.png" alt="Print" />
  </a>


</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add below css:

```
#share-buttons{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Please have a look at this link

https://jsfiddle.net/amzdLxc4/2/